# QTreeWidgetItem without new as member

Tags: c++, qt

```
class A
{
QTreeWidget Tree;
QTreeWidgetItem Item;
QTreeWidgetItem* pointer;
}

A::A()
{
...
Item = QTreeWidgetItem(&Tree); // Version 1
Item.setText(0, "Item");

pointer = new QTreeWidgetItem(&Tree); // Version 2
pointer->setText(0, "Pointer");
...
}
```

Sorry for not providing a full example, I hope this is sufficient.

Version 2 works fine, the Item is shown in the Tree in the GUI. Version 1 does not work (the item is not shown). Why?

The object is still alive (i.e. not destroyed).

Comment: Hint: look at the documentation for `operator=`. In general, avoid version 1. The tree is going to take ownership of the items.

Comment: "In general, avoid version 1". That counts for Qt, right?  I mean, apart from the initialization list I know no other way to create member objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1, you're initializing `Item` by assigning another `QTreeWidgetItem`to it. But the `QTreeWidgetItem` copy assignment doesn't copy everything:

> **QTreeWidgetItem & QTreeWidgetItem::operator=(const QTreeWidgetItem &
>   other)**
>
> Assigns other's data and flags to this item. Note that type() and
>   treeWidget() are not copied.

Comment: @kiigass sorry, the answer's accepted but I've just realized it's wrong, I'll correct it. If QTreeWidgetItem was a QObject, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: That means, there is no way to create these Items, but "new"? Initialization list is no option for me, since the parent does not exist, when the initialization list is "called".

Comment: Creating with new is not a problem because the TreeWidget will manage its items. You won't have to delete them yourself.

Comment: really? I mean, the TreeWidget will even make the delete for me? (Ok, already answered. Overlapped in time)

Comment: Yes, there's a parent-child relationship, as for the QWidgets. The parent automatically deletes its children when it's deleted (and the children can also be deleted manually even if the parent is still alive).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101937/discussion-between-kiigass-and-ilya).